# Using Carbon I got "textual month could not be found" error

Tags: laravel-5, php-carbon

In my Laravel 5.8 application, I to convert date in string format like
`02 May, 2019` to date time using Carbon. I try like :

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'en');
$filter_check_in_datepicker_till = Carbon::createFromFormat( 'dd MMMM YYY', $filter_check_in_datepicker_till )->locale('en_EN');;
```

But got error:

> "message": "Unexpected data found.\nA textual month could not be found\nData missing",

Which is right way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Carbon docs](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation) say:

> createFromFormat() is mostly a wrapper for the base php function DateTime::createFromFormat.

It isn't entirely clear from the docs, but that means the $format parameter passed to `createFromFormat()` is a `DateTime` format, *not* a Carbon format.  So instead of `dd MMMM YYY`, you should use `d, M Y` (check the [DateTime format reference](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)):

```php
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d, M Y', '02, May 2019');
// returns 2019-05-02 12:48:26
```

For reference, there are several problems in your Carbon format, so even if `createFromFormat` took a Carbon format string what you have would not work.  Checking the [Carbon format reference](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-localization):

- `dd` is actually "Minified day name (from Su to Sa), transatable".  You really want `DD` for the zero-padded day of month;
- The date format you are using includes a comma, but your format string is missing that;
- `YYY` is not actually a valid Carbon format string.  You really wanted `YYYY` for 4-digit year;